# After update to 7-2.8 "Conditions" not working

Tags: 7

It seems that after the update to the latest version 2.8 the Conditions section stopped working. No matter which condition I try to choose, nothing happens - my browser just keeps cycling forever.
Anyone has the same problem or a solution?
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "conditions"? The module Conditions only goes to version 6-2.5?  do you mean conditions within the module "Rules"?

Comment: Yes. But... but it's strange. In the meantime, I read something about this being provoked by jQuery. So I installed jQuery Update. The problem remained. Then I rolled back Rules to 2.7. I could get to the Data Selector but no dropdown. I went to jQuery Update and selected 1.5 as default. Then everything worked fine. So, I put jQuery to 1.10 again and ... it still worked fine. So, I upgraded Rules to 2.8 and ... it is still working. So, now I feel really stupid, as I don't know what happened and why. :)

Comment: Well, no one can help if they don't know what you're talking about, so you need to edit the question so people know you're actually talking about Rules and not Conditions - or close the question if you have since answered it yourself